# How to find pdf of exponential random variable given the mean

Tags: exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be a  exponential random variable with mean $\beta$.

How we can write the PDF of $X$ given mean $\beta$.

Let $Y$ random variable define by 
$$ Y=\frac{P}{N}X$$
were $N$ and $P$ are positive real value. What is the PDF and CDF of Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- An exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ has pdf $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and CDF $1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x \ge 0$, and has mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$
- $Y$ is also exponentially distributed, with mean $\frac{P}{N}E[X]$

Comment: OK How we drive the CDF and PDF?

Comment: You know that the mean is $\beta$ and you also know that the mean ist $\frac 1 \lambda$. Now you have $\lambda$ which gives you both the PDF and CDF.

Comment: So if mean is $\frac{P}{N}E[X]$, the pdf is $\frac{N}{PE[X]}e^{-\frac{Nx}{PE[X]}}$